# Hold an object in the memory for a specific time (C# WinForms application)

Tags: c#, memory, caching

What is the best way to hold an object in the memory for a limited period of time, then to free it?
For example, I have a `Dictionary<int, string>` and I want to keep it for 10 minutes only, and after then to dispose it.

How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot dispose dictionaries, only the garbage collector gets rid of them.  Setting the dictionary reference to null in a timer's Tick event would get the job done, eventually.  Look at the WeakReference class.

Comment: Correct,t but my intention wasn't to "Dispose" it, but to not hold it in memory anymore. The terminology wasn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the object cache class (framework 4) according ms documentation is defined this way:
public abstract class ObjectCache : IEnumerable>, 
    IEnumerable

The class belogs to System.Runtime.Caching. In order to Use it you have inherit it into a concrete implementation.

This object works in the same way the httpcache application works, so you can define lets say a sliding expiration and/also an absolute expiration time as well

Comment: ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    string fileContents = cache["filecontents"] as string;

    if (fileContents == null)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        
        List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
        filePaths.Add("c:\\cache\\example.txt");

        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new 
        HostFileChangeMonitor(filePaths));

        // Fetch the file contents.fileContents = 
            File.ReadAllText("c:\\cache\\example.txt");
        
        cache.Set("filecontents", fileContents, policy);
    }

Answer (score 0):

From .NET framework 4.0 and higher you can use `MemoryCache` - it has similar functionality as `HttpCache` and you don't have to include enterprise library (i.e. caching application block).

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Assembly: `System.Runtime.Caching.dll`

Namespace: `System.Runtime.Caching`